# Why is my animation glitching

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

Render as GIF:
[image: render]

See render at this link:
https://vimeo.com/645684750/c5512e2953

Stills look fine, but when I animate everything is glitching

Render settings:
[image: render 1]

[image: render2]

Camera settings:

[image: camera settings]

Comment: Since you don't mention z-fighting as a ruled out possibility, have you checked if you have overlapping meshes? It may be you disabled duplicates visibility in viewport, but not in render.

Comment: It could well be - could you point me in the right direction for where to find out about that please?

Comment: For starters, press Alt+H in viewport to reveal everything. In outliner, enable "disable in viewports" option, so that you can scroll through all objects and see if there are some that are disabled in viewport but not disabled in render. https://i.imgur.com/GEgBg66.png